# How to remove a listener bound to an anonymous function?

Tags: vue.js, event-listener

In my component I have a listener attached to an anonymous function.

Hw can I remove that listener later on since there's no function name to designate the function attached to it?

```
mounted() {
  EventBus.$on('setStickyHeaderCaption', (payload) => {
    ...
  });
},
beforeDestroy() {
  EventBus.$off('setStickyHeaderCaption');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

There's no way to definitively determine which listener you'd destroy because, as you put it, you used an anonymous function as the callback.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that calling `EventBus.$off('setStickyHeaderCaption')` without second argument will remove all listeners attached to that component instance. Since I have just that one listener, that would be an acceptable solution for my case correct?

Comment: @drake035 Yes, if you're not worried about any additional bindings, this will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Without saving a reference to the function there is no way.

You can do something like this:

```
mounted() {
  this.anon = (payload) => {
   ...
  }
  EventBus.$on('setStickyHeaderCaption', this.anon);
},
beforeDestroy() {
  EventBus.$off('setStickyHeaderCaption', this.anon);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand what is `this.anon` though? Should I define a variable called `anon` in the `data() {}` part of my component or?

Comment: @drake035 What he's done is to alias the function to a varaible called `anon` bound to the `data` of the component. This allows you to bind and unbind without being `anonymous` and won't remove other globally scoped listeners on that event.

Comment: Oh ok thanks so I don't need to declare `anon` in my `data(){}` then correct?

Answer (score 0):

Event listener is usually identified by a function that was provided. If a function is anonymous, a listener cannot be removed.

This is the case for Vue method. Methods are already bound to Vue instance and don't need to be arrows:

```
methods: {
  setStickyHeaderCaptionHandler(payload) {...}
},
mounted() {
  EventBus.$on('setStickyHeaderCaption', this.setStickyHeaderCaptionHandler);
},
beforeDestroy() {
  EventBus.$off('setStickyHeaderCaption', this.setStickyHeaderCaptionHandler);
}
```

That methods are accessible outside the component and can be spied or mocked also makes testing easier.